# Regexp to match full Exception name

Tags: java, regex

I need a regexp to get the whole exception name incl. dots from stacktrace and it's a whitespace before it.

```
Time: Sun Apr 10 20:36:57 CEST 2011
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.hello.World.Hi.initDB(bla.java:273)
```

Comment: StKiller, really? "java.lang.*"

Comment: It could be confusing halfdan cause i need to parse emails with that kind of content

Comment: @halfdan - well there are so many cases where a log need to be parsed. So the "java.lang.*" doesn't really specify the parser's implementation language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
String test = "Time: Sun Apr 10 20:36:57 CEST 2011\nMessage: java.lang.NullPointerException\n   at com.hello.World.Hi.initDB(bla.java:273)";
Pattern check = Pattern.compile(".*Message:(\\s[\\w\\.]*)");
Matcher checker = check.matcher(test);
while(checker.find())
{
    System.out.println(checker.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, if you want to match with "Exception" word - there is a way:

```
String test = "Time: Sun Apr 10 20:36:57 CEST 2011\nMessage: java.lang.NullPointerException\n   at com.hello.World.Hi.initDB(bla.java:273)";
Pattern check = Pattern.compile("(\\s[\\w\\.]*Exception)");
Matcher checker = check.matcher(test);
while(checker.find())
{
   System.out.println(checker.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Well, if you don't know what comes before and after java.lang.NullPointerException - there is no way to match it because [\\w\\.] will match any data of type "aaa.AAAA......"

Comment: But there is stil the way to match it with ..Exception  isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Does 'Message' always prefix the exception? If so, then this will grab the exception into a capture group for you:

```
Message:(\s[a-zA-Z\.]*)
```

I'm not sure from your question whether you need to capture the space before or not - if you don't, then remove the `\s` from this regex.

If your exceptions follow convention (ie: are always suffixed with Exception) then you could simply do this:

```
([a-zA-Z\.]*Exception)
```

Comment: No, it could be anything before the whitespace

Comment: @Natalia Naumova: I've updated my answer. If these solutions aren't workable then you may be better to post some more examples of the text you'll need to run the regex against.

Comment: @Natalia Naumova: Fantastic! Can you click the tick next to the answer? Also, as @Joris Meys says, please do the same with the answers that helped on your other questions.